# How to combine 4 characters into 1 character

Tags: c

This is driving me nuts because I don't know the magic words to search for to find a solution.

I initialize:

`unsigned char foo[] = {'0', 'x', '1', '1'};`

`unsigned char bar[] = {'\0'};`

Essentially I want bar[0] to be equal to the value 0x11. How do I do that? I feel stupid and I'm pretty sure there's a simple solution but I can't figure it out. I tried

`memcpy(&bar[0], &foo[0], 1);`

But that just makes bar[0] have the value of 0x30, which is the ascii value of the '0' character.

Any help/hints?

Comment: Could you please clarify why the heading is about **combining** 4 characters into 1 character? All you need is a simple assignment without touching a 4-byte array, which is strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to convert text values to integer, that can be done via [`sscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) function:

```
char * string = "0x11";
int numeric;
sscanf(string, "%i", &numeric);
// numeric is now 0x11
```

Note that:

- `string` actually has five characters, as there is a terminating zero at the end. If you ran C-string-expecting function on unterminated array {'0', 'x', '1', '1'} you had above, if would continue processing data past the array, which is something you definitely do not want.
- In real world use with externally-supplied data, you'd have to check for return value of sscanf to make sure it really did the conversion you wanted to do.

Comment: Yes that's the one I'm looking for! Thank you! My question is poorly formulated, my apologies.

Comment: @Terence: No problem. It will serve as a beacon to other people who are looking for the right vocabulary :-)

Answer (score 3):

The notation `'a'` converts the character `a` to a number, as defined by the [ASCII system](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Therefore,

```
unsigned char foo[] = {'0', 'x', '1', '1'};
```

is actually

```
unsigned char foo[] = {48, 120, 49, 49};
```

or, in hex

```
unsigned char foo[] = {0x30, 0x78, 0x31, 0x31};
```

So, what you need is to simply

```
unsigned char bar[] = { 0x11 };
```

or

```
bar[0] = 0x11;
```

if you already have `bar` defined somewhere.

Comment: How does this answer the question? There's no parsing/conversion in here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, @AlexeyFrunze. If you look up the ASCII table you'll see that the character corresponding to 0x11 is difficult to represent as a user-viewable character. Therefore, conversion from a character constant is not the best way to go here. This answers the question directly, but also explains what is going on so that the OP will grok how the language works.

Comment: I think the OP's intention is to parse the string of characters (`'0','x','1','1'`) in the same way the compiler does when it sees `0x11` in the source code and replace that string with value 0x11.

Comment: Btw, the C standard does not guarantee you that characters are `ASCII`. They could be `EBCDIC`, although that's a rarity these days.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, the OP may then select a different answer and ask a better-defined question next time. You are correct that `ASCII` isn't guaranteed, my apologies. Section 6.4.4.4 of the C99 standard states that "With a few exceptions detailed later, the elements of the sequence are any members of the source character set; they are mapped in an implementation-defined manner to members of the execution character set."

Answer (score 2):

I think your question could be a bit wrong formulated and you may want the first alement of `bar` to have the value that you get when converting the string `foo` to an hexadecimal integer:

```
char foo[] = "0x11";
char bar[1];
bar[0] = (char)strtol(foo, NULL, 0);
```

In your original initialisation of `foo` you miss the trailing `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way you can do it:(And there's more too)

If you want to convert: `unsigned char foo[] = {'0', 'x', '1', '1'};` into `0x11` and store it in `unsigned char bar[] = {'\0'};` Do this:

```
unsigned char foo[] = {'0', 'x', '1', '1', '\0'};//Add end of string character, to be sure
unsigned char bar[] = {'\0'};//Allocated 1 byte of memory
bar[0]=strtol(foo,NULL,16);//Include stdlib.h. Converts strings to long int and due to assignment, result downgraded to unsigned char
```